# Multisite mu-plugins site-specific directory

Tags: plugins, multisite

Is it possible to have a must-use directory within the multisite system that is specific to each individual site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the constants `WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR` and `WPMU_PLUGIN_URL` depending on the host or path in you `wp-config.php`.